# How to add spacing between list items in listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here i have a problem, which is i need the list items in listbox should be have spacing. But my bad luck, i cannot make it. Is that possible or not. Can anyone help me please. I already google it, but i could not find a specific solution.

Code:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //if(!IsPostBack)
            //{
                string search = txt_search.Text;
                if (search != "")

                    lstbox_work.Items.Clear();
                    string[] ext = new string[] { ".pptx", ".xlsx", ".docx", ".xls", ".pdf" };
                    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.1.12\files\workinstruction", txt_search.Text + "*.*").Where(s => ext.Any(n => s.EndsWith(n)));

                    IComparer mycomparer = new myReverserClass();
                    string[] sarray = files.ToArray();

                    DateTime[] creationtime = new DateTime[sarray.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < sarray.Length; i++)
                        creationtime[i] = new FileInfo(sarray[i]).CreationTime;
                    Array.Sort(creationtime, sarray, mycomparer);

                    foreach (string file in sarray)
                    {
                        lstbox_work.Items.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(file), file)); //here the item is listed without spacing. i need the items list with spacing 
                    }

                    {
                        txt_search.Text = "";
                    }
```

Regards,

Thanes

Comment: Show us your code. It should be as simple as adding an empty line after each item in your list.

Comment: In your loop, after you add the item, just add another blank item: `lstbox_work.Items.Add("");`

Comment: Thanks my Friend..it is working...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since list items render as html options, you could add a bit of CSS.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Page Title</title>

    <style>
        option {
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }
    </style>
```

If you want to apply it to a specific listbox you can do this:

```
  <style>
       #ListBox1 option {
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }
    </style>
```